# Eliminar repositorios archivados de GitHub

Tags: git, github

Tengo un problema con mi cuenta de GitHub, el cual se me muestran una lista de repositorios que no son míos.

Me aparecen como `Arcihved` algunos de ellos. Son unos repositorios que hice pequeñas aportaciones por el Hacktoberfest, los cuales desde mi cuenta los elimine, pero siguen estando ahi, y ahora al entrar en alguno no me aparece la opción de "Settings" para poder eliminarlo. Os dejo una imagen de lo que me refiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Hay alguna forma por consola de eliminar esto?**

Parece una tonteria, pero se me hace muy incomodo gestionar mis repositorios con todo ese listado ( que es mas grande de como se muestra en la lista).

Lo he intentado desde la misma pagina, en diferentes opciones y no encuentro una forma de eliminarlos. Si entro en mi perfil, no están. Solo se muestran ahí.

Comment: Puedes probar desarchivarlo y luego eliminarlo